# static factory within an abstract class in typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the following:

```js
export type JSONable = Record<string, string | number>

export type Processable = {
  process(args?: JSONable): Promise<void>
}

abstract class AbstractTaskProcessor<T extends JSONable> implements Processable {

  abstract process(args?: T): Promise<void>

}
```

this is part of my job system.  But sometimes for testing I want to test the process method right away, so I wanted to add a static helper method like so

```js
abstract class AbstractTaskProcessor<T extends JSONable> implements Processable {

  abstract process(args?: T): Promise<void>

  static runNow(args?: T): Promise<void> {
    const instance = new this()
    return instance.process(args)
  }
}
```

but i get a `TS2511: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.`

I would like the DSL to be something like ...

```js
MyTaskProcessor.runNow({accountId: 123123, accountName: 'Lorum' })
```

Does anyone have a good pattern for this?

---

I am on TS 4.2

Comment: aren't you supposed to test only concrete class behaviors? I mean, isn't instantiating an abstract class kind of defeats the purpose of having an abstract class in the first place? You'd probably want to silence the compiler this time if this is the only way you can test the `process` method right now (curious what others think, though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your example work if you just typecast how @ccarton showed. But if it's only for tests and you want to preserve the type information of `T extends JSONable`, I would suggest writing a function for it like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgygeQHIEMBGAbaBeKAlCAYwHsAnAEwB4BnYUgSwDsBzAGiloZagB8pGArgFs0EUgD4AUJNCQoABVLFCEatXRZKAFXFRcAb0lQoYJSrUAKFKWbUA-AC4oWgJRPFxIfWoRKAN2J6cikAX2l0ThRCYChCDBQ1KABBNEjorQSAaw9zajJtKAgAD2AIRnJqWERUTAhdeiEwLCEy4Eqc1XVa7V1DIygIuiiY02VOqxt7J1d3JS8ff0Dg6WNaFGB6QihSAUYkYgB3AuLS8sr4ZA06idtHZzcFOe9fAKDe-uMSRlooJjXGFR6fgQA5QCzAAAW3gGlRQjBALgsLgA3AB6VHAiDkKCyIgJDbcCFiCAfX4AM3B4AgxDJv2+wDhKgAdKNclAAITYXAAIjJu2i9GIjG5LighmMEolkKUBwsAHIAMJwqBCjAgKCiKACHzYoVQOACNBxBI+ahylyksKS0gQYACUiMOn-Zms8bWWwW4xhMKSY2JACyIAy1GyZk6ZEKJTKFWMKTSwGDobGany+lKtCcghEYnY6eAACYnJwmMwQu9JSYw5Z3VMxXnM8JRKRc6oC0W6CWQg8PPMXktyxWJTa7Q7Hp5nkybXkMH4IEjkaSoN7pMUwGQYnyARs9Ts9odjlGzlVLrVxBZXSnSAr4mpMyCwaLsLoOmorj12DXpqLxbEhT8-gyAI4MCoIXnkV43tQ879MO9qOgBjIQCyVZQTWFo+ru+yyoGiYvuB7Bpq2TgAKwtrQhZQNyRIYBgxDcl2kiYYcFg4VkeFkAR9ZQKROKthRADMXZQOizhUlAcpZk2cq-JUjDEDEJr0MwjBXDixA4mJcrFiwcqSKxIbsaQk67FhFiERm3FkW2UCCaKIlyRpkDqGStogOwDkHNYjAlkAA):

```js
class MyTaskProcessor extends  AbstractTaskProcessor<{test: number, test2: string}> {
     process(args?: {test: number, test2: string}): Promise<void> {
         return Promise.resolve();
     }
}

type Processable<T> = {
  process(args?: T): Promise<void>
}

export function runNow<T extends JSONable>(processorClass: new () => Processable<T>, args: T) {
  const instance = new processorClass();
  return instance.process(args)
}

runNow(MyTaskProcessor, {test: 5, test2: "hello"})
runNow(MyTaskProcessor, {test: 5, test2: 3}) // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
MyTaskProcessor.runNow({test: 5, test2: 3}) // no typesafety, no warning
```

**Updated with a refined version from @Linda Paiste**

Comment: This is a nice version since it does not require instantiation of the abstract class and does not define methods on the class *just* for testing purposes.

Comment: super interesting.  What is that infer syntax?

also kind a bummer that `MyTaskProcessor.runNow` does not have typesafty -- i would have hoped that it could have

Comment: I've updated the answer with a short description of infer and a link to the documentation.

Comment: okay -- last clarifying question -- why is it necessary to add the `typeof instance.process !== "function"` typecheck.  What else could it be?

Comment: It is not necessary. I've wanted initially to give a full answer which also included the part ccarton described in his answer. But his answer came first, and this is just a remnant of the static runNow example I used (you can see my full code in the playground). It was supposed to act as a runtime safeguard if someone calls AbstractTaskProcessor.runNow, since there is no compile time safeguard due to the "as any"-cast. I will update the answer and remove it.

Comment: @Jonathan "also kind a bummer that MyTaskProcessor.runNow does not have typesafty -- i would have hoped that it could have" In your specific case, your concrete task processors have a fixed `T` which doesn't depend on the instance but that's not a requirement.  The `T` in a generic class is a "property" of the instance so it doesn't make sense to access `T` on an abstract method which doesn't have a `T`.

Comment: @Micro S.  I would tweak the `class` definition to ensure that the constructor doesn't require any arguments (or require that the constructor args be passed to `runNow`).  But this is a very good answer.  It's nice to see new answerers who are really knowledgeable :)

Comment: Modified version with no `infer` and a generic `Processable<T>`: https://tsplay.dev/Woq5LN

Comment: @MircoS.  I think Linda Paiste's solution could be considered more elegant if you want to consider updating your answer (though I did enjoy learning about infer)

Answer (score 2):

Abstract constructor signatures are now supported as of Typescript 4.2. See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-2/#abstract-construct-signatures

If for some reason you aren't able to upgrade, the old solution requires a regular constructor signature and a type assertion:

```
type JSONable = Record<string, string | number>

type Processable = {
  process(args?: JSONable): Promise<void>
}

type ProcessableConstructor = { new (): Processable }  // Constructor signature

abstract class AbstractTaskProcessor<T extends JSONable> implements Processable {

  abstract process(args?: T): Promise<void>

  static runNow<T extends JSONable> (args?: T): Promise<void> {
    const instance = new (this as any as ProcessableConstructor)()   // Type assertion
    return instance.process(args)
  }
}

class MyTaskProcessor extends AbstractTaskProcessor<JSONable> {
  async process (args: JSONable) { return }
}

MyTaskProcessor.runNow({accountId: 123123, accountName: 'Lorum' })
```

Comment: Can you post an example how he wouldn't have to typecast with the abstract keyword? I don't see how this would change the need to typecast.